# Neo4j: Comparing two lists with CONTAINS

Tags: database, neo4j, cypher

I have two lists, ListA it's ingredients with their literal name like ['eggs', 'sugar'] and on ListB i have ingredients like ['salted eggs', 'sugar powder']. I was wondering how could i compare each member of listA with each member on listB in a way that 'eggs' matches with 'salted eggs' and 'sugar' matches with 'sugar powder'. I know it's with CONTAINS which helps matching a substring inside another string but i can't figure out how to do this comparison between the two lists.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example query that shows the behaviour of using list comprehension together with the `ANY` predicate :

```
WITH 
['eggs', 'sugar'] AS list1, 
['salted eggs', 'sugar powder', 'other ingredient'] AS list2
RETURN [x IN list1 WHERE 
             ANY(z IN list2 WHERE z CONTAINS x)
] AS matchingElements
```